# How can a person receive an expired life vest?

Tags: safety

I wonder if passengers could receive an expired life vest because who else would they give to.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Are you asking how you can get an expired life vest because you would like to own one? From the title, I thought you were asking how passengers could be mistakenly given expired life vests to use in emergency situations.

Comment: I think the poster wants to try one out, just as shown in this video about [Aircraft Life Vest Full Detailed Demonstration](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=d_XaIQTT5WI). But yes, @TerranSwett, the title is ambiguous.

Comment: If you want one, try eBay - there are plenty available.

Answer (score 2):

[You can buy aircraft life vests pretty inexpensively](https://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/pspages/switlik13-16032.php?gclid=Cj0KCQiA-bjyBRCcARIsAFboWg15HSOLp8n8HYcIegv904wX7jzAHRzct2ZkwTb3INJGMhKtcr-SuokaAupxEALw_wcB) for the purpose of having one or seeing how they work.

[There are a bunch of used ones for sale on eBay](https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/airline-life-vest/bn_7024959987), they may have been taken from planes over the years or they may just find their way into circulation after being removed (before being trashed).

[Some of them get upcycled/recycled into other things](https://www.asiaone.com/travel/airasia-upcycling-old-life-jackets-lifestyle-products) so they presumably enter circulation at some point.